# Getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 on bulk insert with Node JS mysql2

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I'm trying to do a bulk insert in Nodejs using the mysql2 package, but the code keeps erroring out on me, and I can't seem to figure out why since as far as I can tell, the number of data elements and columns match up. Here are the relevant code pieces:

db.js

```
const config = require('../config');

async function query(sql, params) {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(config.db);
    const [results, ] = await connection.execute(sql, params);

    return results;
}

module.exports = {
    query
}
```

importData.js

```
const db = require('./db');

async function insertRow(data) {
    console.log(data);
    await db.query('INSERT INTO table (Vendor, `Account No`, `Secondary Contact`, `Bill From`, `Alt. Phone`, `Alt. Mobile`, `Main Email`, `Primary Contact`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Main Phone`, `Work Phone`, `Home Phone`, `Mobile Phone`, Fax, `Balance Total`, `Vendor Type`, `Tax ID`) VALUES (?)',
    [data], (error, results) => {
        if (error) return results.json({ error: error });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    testQuery,
    insertRow
}
```

importController.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");
const importData = require('../services/importData');
const { delimiter } = require("path");

module.exports = {
  importFile() {
    var delimiter = ",,";
    var result = [];
    fs.createReadStream("./testFile.csv")
    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: delimiter, from_line: 2 }))
    .on("data", function (row) {
      //console.log(row);
      result.push(row);
    })
    .on("end", function () {
      //console.log(result);
      importData.insertRow(result);
      //console.log("finished");
    })
    .on("error", function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }
}
```

a section of the results array that I'm trying to insert from the VSCode console:

```
0:
(19) ['1800 FLOWERS', '', '', '1800 FLOWERS', '', '', 'test@testemail.com', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '']
2:
(19) ['23 ATLANTIC AVE', '', '', '23 ATLANTIC AVE', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '']
3:
(19) ['A AND D', '', '', 'A AND D', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '']
```

and lastly the route:

```
exports.routesConfig = function(app) {
    app.get("/test", [
        importController.importFile
    ])
}
```

When I send the request to the route, I get this:

```
(node:13748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at PromiseConnection.execute (C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\Data\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:112:22)
    at Object.query (C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\Data\services\db.js:6:42)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Object.insertRow (C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\Data\services\importData.js:18:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
warning.js:44
(node:13748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
warning.js:44
(node:13748) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any idea what's going on since as far as I can tell, the number of entries in each array matches the number of columns in the table minus the auto incrementing id?